# React - State not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I try to set `state.autocomplete` to 'hello' and then print it, but state seems to be null. How can that be when I just updated the state using `setState`? `data` is set as a global variable.

```
  var data = {
    populate_at: ['web_start', 'web_end'],
    autocomplete_from: ['customer_name', 'customer_address']
  };


  var AutocompleteFromCheckboxes = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function(e) {
      this.setState( { autocomplete_from: 'event.target.value' } );
      console.log('autocompleteFrom state: ', this.state.autocomplete_from);
      // ^  => Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete_from' of null
      return 1;
    },
    render: function() {
      var autocompleteFrom = this.props.autocomplete_from.map(function(value) {
        return (
          <label for={value}>
            <input type="checkbox" name={value} value="{value}"
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              ref="autocomplete-from"/>
            {value}
          </label>
        );
      }, this);
      return (
        <div className="autocomplete-from">
          {autocompleteFrom}
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  var DynamicForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        name              : null,
        populate_at       : null,
        same_as           : null,
        autocomplete_from : "not set",
        title             : null
      };
    },
    saveAndContinue: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {
        name     : this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value,
      };
      console.log('data: ' + data.name);
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
          <AutocompleteFromCheckboxes
            autocomplete_from={this.props.data.autocomplete_from} />
      );
    }
  });


  var mountpoint = document.getElementById('dynamic-form');
  if ( mountpoint ) {
    React.render(<DynamicForm data={data} />, mountpoint);
  }

});
```

Comment: @zvona, adding `.bind(this)` caused this warning `Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See AutocompleteFromCheckboxes
dynamic-form.js?body=1:13 populateAtCheckbox`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. My mistake :/.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

From the reactjs docs:

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

What you can do is pass a callback function to `setState` which is triggered once the state has been updated:

```js
this.setState(
    {autocomplete_from: ...}, 
    function () {
        ... at this point the state of the component is set ...
    }
)
```

Comment: Nice, that was it. `console.log` outputs as expected now. :-)

Comment: Seems like a very ugly way of doing that. I don't understand why they didn't include a stateHasChanged event, so you can just listen to statechanges with onStateChanged or something alike.

Comment: One can be tempted to use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) for this but there's no guarantee it will be called after calling `setState` – [*If `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, then `render()` will be completely skipped until the next state change. In addition, `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` will not be called.*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate).

Comment: Related: [ReactJS: What is the difference between componentDidUpdate and the second parameter of setState?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29799687/95735)

Comment: I appreciate this. I can console.log the correct data out but how do I get it to render now? I thought that setState caused a new render?

Comment: `console.log(co_code); //Prints new code
console.log(region);//Prints new region
this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        provided_region:region,
        provided_co_code:co_code,
      },function () {console.log(this.state);console.log('in callback');}); //Does not print new value`

Comment: I am not able to put line break (tried putting two spaces)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the initial state of your component, try adding the following to the top of your component.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
   autocomplete_from: ''
  };
}
```

EDIT:

In your DynamicFrom component you have:

```
render: function() {
  return (
      <AutocompleteFromCheckboxes
        autocomplete_from={this.props.data.autocomplete_from} />
  );
}
```

Since you are trying to reference the state you should write

```
autocomplete_form={this.state.autocomplete_from}
```

Also you are trying to set the state from a child component and it should not directly modify state. The best way to approach this is to pass down a function from DynamicFrom(holds the state) to AutocompleteFromCheckboxes. Like so.

```
var DynamicForm = React.createClass({
    handleChange: function(value) {
       this.setState({autocompelete_from: value});
    },
    render: function() {
       return(
          <AutocompleteFromCheckboxes 
            autocomplete_from={this.state.autocomplete_from}
            handleChange={this.handleChange} 
          />
       );
    },
    ....
});
```

### Then call that function in your child component

```
AutocompleteFromCheckboxes = React.createClass({
    ....
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    ....
    handleChange: function(e) {
     this.props.handleChange(e.target.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include getInitialState in my original post. Updated the post to include more code now.

Answer (score 2):

To see updated state value after doing setState you should do something like below

```
 this.setState( { autocomplete_from: 'event.target.value' }, () => { 
    console.log(this.state.autocomplete_from);//this will print the updated state value
 });
```