# ReactJS: What is the difference between componentDidUpdate and the second parameter of setState?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

Is there any difference between those 2 functions? (besides their arguments)
It seems like those methods have the same triggers, isn't it?

Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 5):

`componentDidUpdate` is called whenever the component has re-rendered, which might be caused by either:

- a change in state
- a call to `forceUpdate`
- a parent component re-rendering (or another call to `React.render` in the case of the top-level component)

The `setState` callback will only be called once the state transition has completed and the component has re-rendered.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the usage of those two: `componentDidUpdate()` needs to be declared only once per component, while the `callback` argument of `setState()` needs to be passed in every place the `setState()` method is called.

It's like putting all your eggs in one basket: you don't need to carry around different bags, however if you might want to boil some of the eggs and some to make an omelette from, and in this case you use multiple bags.

Comment: You're dead right, I don't need multiple bags to boil an omelette