# State doesn't seem to be getting set - React

Tags: reactjs

The `console.log` below logs out `selected: false`, even though I've just set the state. Why is this?

```
 const App = React.createClass({

     getInitialState : function() {
         return { 
             selected: false
         }
     },

     componentDidMount : function() {
         this.setState({selected: true})
             console.log(this.state);
         },

         render : function() {
             return (
                 <li>test</li>
             );
         }
    });
```

Comment: Because setState is not synchronous, The second argument to setState can be a callback to run once its updated. -- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: Ah yes, just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated