# Implementing React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am slowly learning React and also learning to implement it with Redux. But I seem to have hit a road block. So this is what I have so far.

/index.jsx

```
import './main.css'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App.jsx'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import ShoppingList from './reducers/reducer'

let store = createStore(ShoppingList)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

/actions/items.js

```
import uuid from 'node-uuid'

export const CREATE_ITEM = 'CREATE_ITEM'
export function createItem(item) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_ITEM,
    item: {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      item,
      checked: false
    }
  }
}
```

/reducers/reducer.js

```
import * as types from '../actions/items'
import uuid from 'node-uuid'

const initialState = []

const items = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_ITEM:
      return {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        ...item
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
 }

 export default items
```

/reducers/index.js
UPDATE:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import items from './reducer'

const ShoppingList = combineReducers({
  items
})

export default ShoppingList
```

/components/Item.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import uuid from 'node-uuid'

export default class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isEditing: false
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isEditing) {
      return this.renderEdit();
    }

    return this.renderItem();
  }

  renderEdit = () => {
    return (
      <input type="text"
        ref={(event) => 
          (event ? event.selectionStart = this.props.text.length : null)
        }
        autoFocus={true}
        defaultValue={this.props.text}
        onBlur={this.finishEdit}
        onKeyPress={this.checkEnter} 
      />
    )
  };

  renderDelete = () => {
    return <button onClick={this.props.onDelete}>x</button>;
  };

  renderItem = () => {
    const onDelete = this.props.onDelete;

    return (
      <div onClick={this.edit}>
        <span>{this.props.text}</span>
        {onDelete ? this.renderDelete() : null }
      </div>
    );
  };

  edit = () => {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: true
    });
  };

  checkEnter = (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.finishEdit(e);
    }
  };

  finishEdit = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    if(this.props.onEdit) {
      this.props.onEdit(value);

      this.setState({
        isEditing: false
      });
    }
  };
}
```

/components/Items.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from './Item.jsx';

export default ({items, onEdit, onDelete}) => {
  return (
    <ul>{items.map(item =>
      <li key={item.id}>
        <Item 
          text={item.text} 
          onEdit={onEdit.bind(null, item.id)}
          onDelete={onDelete.bind(null, item.id)}
        />
      </li>
    )}</ul>
  );
}
//  UPDATE: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html
// Is this necessary?
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    state
  }
}

Items = connect(
  mapStateToPros
)(Items) // `SyntaxError app/components/Items.jsx: "Items" is read-only`

//////////////////////////////////////
// Also tried it this way. 
//////////////////////////////////////
Items = connect()(Items)
export default Items // same error as above.
```

Tried this as well

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    items: store.items
  })
)(Items) // `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`
```

UPDATE:

After many attempts @hedgerh in Gitter pointed out that it should be state.items instead. so the solution was

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    items: state.items
  })
)(Items)
```

credits to @azium as well.

/components/App.jsx

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>+</button>
          <Items />
      </div>
    ); 
  } 
}
```

What am I missing here in order to implement it correctly? Right now it breaks saying that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in `Items.jsx`. I guess it makes sense since it doesn't seem to be hooked up correctly. This is the first part of the app, where the second will allow an user to create a many lists, and these lists having many items. I will probably have to extract the methods from `Item.jsx` since the `List.jsx` will do pretty much the same thing. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be missing `App.jsx` in your example.. how is `items` being passed to `<Items />` ?

Comment: Something needs to be `connect`ed to your store.. so either you forgot to show that part or you need to add it somewhere.

Comment: I think thats what I'm unsure. I have an App.jsx, hold on I'll update my question. @azium

Comment: Are you using `<provider>` to pass the store down to it's children? How is the store being passed down? Are you using `connect` inside your App.jsx?

Comment: @James111 I am using `<Provider>` look in my index.js. I do pass the store there too. If I understand it correctly by using `Provider` and passing the store there, that store would be available to my children components. correct? Now how do i connect the app is a bit fuzzy stil.

Comment: Can you post your store file? Are you using a middleware such as `thunk`?

Comment: @James111 I dont have a store file, I instantiate my `createStore` in my `index.jsx` file. I guess I could split that up to a different file.

Comment: You're importing the wrong file in your `index.jsx`. You're importing the contents of `reducers/reducer` not `reducers/index`

Comment: @Diego - Oh. Well if you're thinking of building a bigger application checkout this started kit and how it connects & handles the reducers. https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit

Comment: Is `Items` actually defined in your `Items.jsx` file? I don't see it ever defined anywhere before trying to assign it when you do `Items = connect(` -- which, I know you pointed out you have tried other ways. On those other attempts though, you're still passing `Items` in to the resulting function of calling connect (remember: connect is a higher-order function). It seems like `Items` would be undefined at that point?

Comment: Also, thought it would be worth pointing out (again, totally understandable as you said you are new to this stuff :) !), you should very rarely be using `setState` in your Redux-connected React components. In an answer I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36252411/2476218), I explained a bit about the theory behind using Redux and why you don't want to use `setState` -- short answer: Redux should be handling your state changes as passing state down as props, rather than changing state within components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `connect`. That's how stuff gets from your store to your components. Read the containers section from the docs http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

```
import React from 'react'
import Item from './Item.jsx'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

let Items = ({items, onEdit, onDelete}) => {
  return (
    <ul>{items.map(item =>
      <li key={item.id}>
        <Item 
          text={item.text} 
          onEdit={onEdit.bind(null, item.id)}
          onDelete={onDelete.bind(null, item.id)}
        />
      </li>
      })
  </ul>
  )
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    items: state.items
  })
)(Items)
```

Also you seem to be expecting `onEdit` and `onDelete` functions passed from a parent but you're not doing that so those functions will be undefined.

Comment: It says it can't find the `store` I created my store in my `index.jsx` Should I create it in a different file? say `stores/store.js` and then import that here? @azium

Comment: You're importing the wrong file in `index.jsx`. It should be `import ShoppingList from './reducers'`. Currently you're importing the reducer without calling `combineReducers`

Comment: After your suggested changes i'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined` in my `Items.jsx` at `store.items`

Comment: export default connect(
  state => ({
    items: state.items
  })
)(Items)

Comment: @Diego I think in @azium's example, it was meant that `export default connect(state => ({ items: store.items}))(Items)` would actually be this:

    `export default connect(
        state => ({
            items: state.items
        })
    )(Items)`

Comment: Notice, the difference is `state.items` vs. `store.items`

Comment: @marcacyr that's correct, I had updated my question, and included the answer in it. Thanks =)

Comment: Oh gosh yes Diego & marcacyr thank you for catching that.