# How to get the latest selected value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    console.log("You picked up" + this.state.value);
  }



<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
```

I just wonder why the handleChange() always returns me the previous selected vlaue rather than the currently selected?

Here is my full code:
https://codepen.io/franva/pen/owbmaQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated. This behavior is described in detail here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change state on click react js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/change-state-on-click-react-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState()` is asynchronous. Try

```
this.setState({ value: event.target.value }, () => {
  console.log("You picked up" + this.state.value);
});
```

Comment: thanks ~! I didn't know setState has a callback ~! :)