# Pasting of text is being duplicated in textbox in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I can't figure out why after pasting in my email, it duplicates it in the textbox.

[screencast of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xt8HXs4j-c&feature=youtu.be)

It appears that **when I paste, it correctly triggers `handleEmailPaste` but I also noticed that `handleEmailPaste` also gets triggered** by the past so not sure why.  I guess pasting is a change, so probably makes sense that pasting in text would trigger both functions.  **If I comment out the code in `handleEmailInput`, and paste in a value, it doesn't duplicate it.**

I guess I don't know the right way to handle this.  Seems to me like I do need two separate handlers though.  Notice that I'm using a bootstrap control and on it, I've got onChange and onPaste set:

```
<FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-username"
              componentClass="input"
              onPaste={this.props.handleEmailPaste}
              onChange={this.props.handleEmailInput}
              placeholder="Enter email"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="email"
              value={this.props.email}
            />
```

**LoginContainer**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
const zxcvbn = require('zxcvbn'),
  _ = require('lodash')

import * as AsyncActions from '../actions/Auth/AuthAsyncActions'
import Login from '../components/Login/Login'



class LoginContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errorMessage: '',
      emailValidationState: null,
      formIsValid: false,
      formValidationState: null,
      passwordValidationState: null,
      passwordIsValid: null
    }

    this.handleEmailPaste = this.handleEmailPaste.bind(this)
    this.handleEmailInput = this.handleEmailInput.bind(this)
    this.handlePasswordInput = this.handlePasswordInput.bind(this)
    this.handleLoginPressed = this.handleLoginPressed.bind(this)
    this.resetFields = this.resetFields.bind(this)
    this.validateForm = this.validateForm.bind(this)
    this.validateEmail = this.validateEmail.bind(this)
    this.validatePassword = this.validatePassword.bind(this)
  }

  handlePasswordInput(e) {
    const password = e.target.value
    this.setState({ password: password})
    this.validatePassword()
  }

  handleEmailPaste(e){
    console.log(`handleEmailPaste: ${e.clipboardData.getData('Text')}`)
    const value = e.clipboardData.getData('Text')
    this.setState({ email: value })
    this.validateEmail(value)
  }

  handleEmailInput(e) {
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
    this.validateEmail()
  }

  async handleLoginPressed(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.validateForm()

    await this.props.authenticate(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
      return
    }

    if(!this.props.isAuthenticated){
      this.setState({
        formValidationState: 'error',
        errorMessage: this.state.formIsValid &&
        'Your password and/or email is not associated with an active user'
      })

      if(this.state.email && this.state.password){this.resetFields()}
    }
  }

  validateForm(){
    this.validateEmail()
    this.validatePassword()
    this.setState({
      formIsValid: (this.state.emailValidationState === 'success'
        && this.state.passwordValidationState === 'success')})
  }

  validatePassword(){
    const password = zxcvbn(this.state.password)
    if(password.score >=0){
      this.setState({
        passwordValidationState: 'error',
        passwordHelpText: password.feedback.suggestions})
      return
    }

    this.setState({
      passwordValidationState: 'success',
      passwordHelpText: null })
  }

  validateEmail(value){
    if((!_.isEmpty(value)) || !_.isEmpty(this.state.email)) {
      this.setState({
        emailValidationState: 'success',
        emailError: ''
      })
      return
    }

    this.setState({
      emailValidationState: 'error',
      emailError: 'please enter an email address'
    })
  }

    resetFields(){
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      emailError: '',
      emailValidationState: null,
      password: '',
      passwordHelpText: '',
      passwordValidationState: null })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Login
          email={this.state.email}
          emailError={this.state.emailError}
          emailValidationState={this.state.emailValidationState}
          errorMessage={this.state.errorMessage}
          formValidationState={this.state.formValidationState}
          handleEmailInput={this.handleEmailInput}
          handleEmailPaste={this.handleEmailPaste}
          handlePasswordInput={this.handlePasswordInput}
          login={this.handleLoginPressed}
          password={this.state.password}
          passwordHelpText={this.state.passwordHelpText}
          passwordValidationState={this.state.passwordValidationState}
        />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticating: state.auth.isAuthenticating,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  token: state.auth.token
})

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  authenticate: AsyncActions.authenticate
}

export { Login }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer)
```

**Login**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import LoginForm from './LoginForm'

export default class Login extends Component {
  render(){
      return (
        <div>
          <LoginForm
            email={this.props.email}
            emailError={this.props.emailError}
            emailValidationState={this.props.emailValidationState}
            errorMessage={this.props.errorMessage}
            formValidationState={this.props.formValidationState}
            handleEmailInput={this.props.handleEmailInput}
            handleEmailPaste={this.props.handleEmailPaste}
            handlePasswordInput={this.props.handlePasswordInput}
            login={this.props.login}
            password={this.props.password}
            passwordHelpText={this.props.passwordHelpText}
            passwordValidationState={this.props.passwordValidationState}
          />
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

**LoginForm**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Button,
  ControlLabel,
  HelpBlock,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  PageHeader } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='ft-login-form'>
        <PageHeader className='ft-header'><small>Login</small></PageHeader>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.login}>
          <FormGroup validationState={this.props.formValidationState}>
            <ControlLabel className="ft-form-error-message">{this.props.errorMessage}</ControlLabel>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText" validationState={this.props.emailValidationState}>
            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-username"
              componentClass="input"
              onPaste={this.props.handleEmailPaste}
              onChange={this.props.handleEmailInput}
              placeholder="Enter email"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="email"
              value={this.props.email}
            />
            <HelpBlock className="ft-email-error">{this.props.emailError}</HelpBlock>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup validationState={this.props.passwordValidationState}>
            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-password"
              componentClass="input"
              onPaste={this.props.handleEmailPaste}
              onChange={this.props.handlePasswordInput}
              placeholder="Enter password"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="password"
              value={this.props.password}
            />
            <HelpBlock className="ft-password-help-text">{this.props.passwordHelpText}</HelpBlock>
          </FormGroup>
          <Button
            className='ft-login-button'
            type='submit'
          >Login</Button>
        </form>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So I added this and this fixes the problem:

```
 handleEmailInput(e) {
    if(!this.state.email) {
      this.setState({email: e.target.value})
    }
    this.validateEmail()
  }
```

basically here I'm saying hey, if someone pasted it in initially, it would have hit `handleEmailPaste` which setsState for email so if that's the case, (and I know that handleEmailInput is also going to be triggered by that paste/change), then I don't want to set state again if handleEmailPaste already set it.  On the contrary if a user typed in a value rather than pasted it, then this if statement would be `bypassed` and therefore `handleEmailInput would setState in that case`.

but my entire handling of email input just feels hacky to me.  If you think that's a hack and have a better idea of refactoring this code let me know.

**UPDATE #2**

crap, I noticed that I don't get duplication but now I can't type a new value in the email box, it won't let me and it just sits there with the populated email but I can't modify it.

**UPDATE #3**
(Rant: why the hell doesn't StackOverflow make the height of the post body textarea bigger, I can barely see what I'm doing in here when I scroll)

So really my problem is no longer the issue of it duping my pasted text.  I'm back to square one, my original problem wheres I was able to paste in something, but it invalidated the input and I couldn't figure out why.  I guess I should update the title of this post but oh well.

Anyway, I've resorted to just using only `onChange` and got rid of onPaste.  No more dups happening

So the problem: Is with the initial behavior when you first paste in a value to the email textbox.  The behavior I see (and below is the updated code without the onPaste anymore) when you paste in a value for the first time:

1. When you paste in the first time, it hits my `handleEmailInput()` method.
2. `handleEmailInput` calls `setState({email: e.target.value})` so you'd think that's set now for this.state.email
3. But when `handleEmailInput` calls `validateEmail()` immediately after, `validateEmail`, it checks `this.state.email` and it's **still** `""` for some reason.  So therefore it **ends up hitting the second setState which sets it to invalid**.

Doesn't the **first call** to `this.setState({email: e.target.value })` set `this.state.email` to the pasted email??  I know that when I put a breakpoint on that line, `e.target.value` **does** have the email I pasted, but **after** `this.setState({email: e.target.value })` is done being called, for some reason when in validateEmail() it's still getting `""` for this.state.email and I don't understand why.  Maybe it's something fundamental with React and its lifecycle? or some other fundamental I'm not aware of yet..not sure.

**LoginContainer**
(I've completely removed onPaste logic)

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
const zxcvbn = require('zxcvbn'),
  _ = require('lodash')

import * as AsyncActions from '../actions/Auth/AuthAsyncActions'
import Login from '../components/Login/Login'

class LoginContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errorMessage: '',
      emailValidationState: null,
      formIsValid: false,
      formValidationState: null,
      passwordValidationState: null,
      passwordIsValid: null
    }

    this.handleEmailInput = this.handleEmailInput.bind(this)
    this.handlePasswordInput = this.handlePasswordInput.bind(this)
    this.handleLoginPressed = this.handleLoginPressed.bind(this)
    this.resetFields = this.resetFields.bind(this)
    this.validateForm = this.validateForm.bind(this)
    this.validateEmail = this.validateEmail.bind(this)
    this.validatePassword = this.validatePassword.bind(this)
  }

  handlePasswordInput(e) {
    const password = e.target.value
    this.setState({ password: password})
    this.validatePassword()
  }

  handleEmailInput(e) {
    this.setState({email: e.target.value })
    this.validateEmail()
  }

  async handleLoginPressed(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.validateForm()

    await this.props.authenticate(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    if(this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
      return
    }

    if(!this.props.isAuthenticated){
      this.setState({
        formValidationState: 'error',
        errorMessage: this.state.formIsValid &&
        'Your password and/or email is not associated with an active user'
      })

      if(this.state.email && this.state.password){this.resetFields()}
    }
  }

  validateForm(){
    this.validateEmail()
    this.validatePassword()
    this.setState({
      formIsValid: (this.state.emailValidationState === 'success'
        && this.state.passwordValidationState === 'success')})
  }

  validatePassword(){
    const password = zxcvbn(this.state.password)
    if(password.score >=0){
      this.setState({
        passwordValidationState: 'error',
        passwordHelpText: password.feedback.suggestions})
      return
    }

    this.setState({
      passwordValidationState: 'success',
      passwordHelpText: null })
  }

  validateEmail(){
    if(!_.isEmpty(this.state.email)) {
      this.setState({
        emailValidationState: 'success',
        emailError: ''
      })

      return
    }

      this.setState({
        emailValidationState: 'error',
        emailError: 'please enter an email address'
      })
  }

  resetFields(){
    this.setState({
      email: '',
      emailError: '',
      emailValidationState: null,
      password: '',
      passwordHelpText: '',
      passwordValidationState: null })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Login
          email={this.state.email}
          emailError={this.state.emailError}
          emailValidationState={this.state.emailValidationState}
          errorMessage={this.state.errorMessage}
          formValidationState={this.state.formValidationState}
          handleEmailInput={this.handleEmailInput}
          handlePasswordInput={this.handlePasswordInput}
          login={this.handleLoginPressed}
          password={this.state.password}
          passwordHelpText={this.state.passwordHelpText}
          passwordValidationState={this.state.passwordValidationState}
        />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticating: state.auth.isAuthenticating,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  token: state.auth.token
})

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  authenticate: AsyncActions.authenticate
}

export { Login }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer)

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Button,
  ControlLabel,
  HelpBlock,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  PageHeader } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

**LoginForm**
(notice we resorted back to only having onChange for email)

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='ft-login-form'>
        <PageHeader className='ft-header'><small>Login</small></PageHeader>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.login}>
          <FormGroup validationState={this.props.formValidationState}>
            <ControlLabel className="ft-form-error-message">{this.props.errorMessage}</ControlLabel>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText" validationState={this.props.emailValidationState}>
            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-username"
              componentClass="input"
              onChange={this.props.handleEmailInput}
              placeholder="Enter email"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="email"
              value={this.props.email}
            />
            <HelpBlock className="ft-email-error">{this.props.emailError}</HelpBlock>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup validationState={this.props.passwordValidationState}>
            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-password"
              componentClass="input"
              onPaste={() => this.props.handleEmailPaste}
              onChange={() => this.props.handlePasswordInput}
              placeholder="Enter password"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="password"
              value={this.props.password}
            />
            <HelpBlock className="ft-password-help-text">{this.props.passwordHelpText}</HelpBlock>
          </FormGroup>
          <Button
            className='ft-login-button'
            type='submit'
          >Login</Button>
        </form>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify it because your `email` is a [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) whose value depends on the `state`, which, because of `if`, is not updating

Comment: ok..well if I take out the if, then it duplicates the value in that box

Comment: yea I'm stuck then if that's the case because I don't know how to get rid of the original problem then if that's the case, whereas I paste in an email and it dups it (somehow it's updating state twice or something, I don't really know)

Comment: I was able to recreate the problem on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3e247avL/3/), maybe let's just work it out together :)

Comment: share the room's url or something....

Comment: I resorted to just using onChange.  Check out my latest update.  And I explain more of what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good that you realized that the `onPaste` was erroneous.  That's halfway to the solution.  :)

The piece you're still missing is that `setState` is an asynchronous function.  Whenever you call `setState`, you are simply queuing new state data.  Part of what makes react so powerful is it's inherent ability to in fact, take multiple `setState` functions and consolidate them into a singular update (and thus, a singular test of whether or not to re-render).

That said, the `setState` function *does* allow for callback functions as a secondary argument.  Use these callbacks to specify what should be done *after* your new state is applied.  It should look something like this;

```
this.setState({email: e.target.value }, this.validateEmail)
```

Comment: did not see this I was posting the same answer as you were typing yours proabably

Comment: plus yours is cleaner!

Comment: Additionally:  I'm not familiar with React-Bootstrap, but generally speaking, inputs should be either dynamic or controlled.  You're setting both an `onChange` function to update state as well as a `value` value, which pulls from the state.  My guess would be that removing the `value` prop would also "solve" the problem of the duplicate input as it would then be setting the state twice still, but setting it to the same value at least.

Comment: well I don't have the dup problem anymore, I removed the onPaste..and it appears that the onChange -was- detecting an email pasted afterall, I thought it wasn't when in fact it was that async setState() issue all along

Comment: @PositiveGuy, it definitely does work without wrapping the function.  Be sure that you are simply referencing the function though, and not calling it (i.e. `this.validateEmail` not `this.validateEmail()`)

Comment: now I caused another issue that I didn't have prior to posting this, I can't type into the password box now lol!  it does nothing when I try

Comment: I think I should call it a night, before I give myself anymore pain, it's almost 2am

Comment: If you haven't already, I would urge removing the value prop from the password `FormControl`.  I think this, and your previous duplication problem, are likely both caused by your component being controlled by it's parent, and passing information to it's parent.  You should really only do one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes n00b here. Found the problem: [React - State not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated)

Solution:

```
  handleEmailInput(e) {
    this.setState({email: e.target.value }, () => {
      this.validateEmail()
    })
  }
```

Now validateEmail is only called once that queued state transition is truly done updating this.state.email.

Answer (score 0):

Related to #3: setState is async, so it is not guaranteed to have updated the state by end of call. Instead you can pass a callback that will be called when state has been updated:

```
this.setState({email: value}, () => { /* State is updated */ });
```

Might not be related to your problem, but you are using "handleEmailPaste" for your password input field.

Also, calling setState multiple times will never append text, so even if it is called twice with the same value, it would not duplicate that value. More likely is that the value passed from the FormControl is wrong in that case. I would add a breakpoint/console.log in both "input" and "paste" callbacks to check what value is passed from the FormControl.

Finally (also unrelated to your problem), in #3, your password events should not be "onEvent={() => this.props.handleXyz}". That will not call the callback. Instead it should be onEvent={this.props.handleXyz}.