# React can't figure out how to send data to my parent accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create this React Vending Machine and I need to send some id values from a child to the parent and then make some functions that require that value

I've managed to make the proper function but it doesn't behave like I want to. When I click the button the first time my query is updated but it is not transferred to the parent component. Only when I click the second time my parent gets updated with the state that it was before. So its always one state late.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      fromChild: ""
    }
  }
  handleData(data) {
  this.setState({
    fromChild: data
  });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Glass />
        <FrontPanel handlerFromParent={this.handleData.bind(this)}/>
        <h5>Received by parent:<br />{this.state.fromChild}</h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



class FrontPanel extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        query: ""
      }


  }

/* function that manages the keybord */
addToQuery = (id) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
  query: prevState.query + id
  }))
  this.onChangeQuery();
}
/* function that sends data to parent */
onChangeQuery() {
  this.props.handlerFromParent(this.state.query)
}
  render() {

    return (
      <div>

          <Screen
            credit={this.state.credit}
            query={this.state.query}/>

          <div className="keybord-layout">
          <div className="keybord">
          <button onClick={e => this.addToQuery(e.target.id)} id="1">1</button>
          <button onClick={e => this.addToQuery(e.target.id)} id="2">2</button>
          <button onClick={e => this.addToQuery(e.target.id)} id="3">3</button>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default FrontPanel;
```

I want when I click a button to transfer the state to the parent immediately and not wait for another button press. Also, I don't want the state to be behind in the parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - State not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `setState` call is asynchronous so `this.state.query` may not yet be updated when you called `this.onChangeQuery();` that calls your parent component handler.

Try calling your parent handler in the callback function that you can pass to `setState`.

```
this.setState(
  prevState => ({
    query: prevState.query + id
  }),
  () => this.onChangeQuery()
);
```

This way, you're ensured that `query` is the new value when you pass it back to parent.

Comment: Yup. [Here's a working version with that change taken in](https://jsfiddle.net/q13vLpbd/).