# How to push to an object to an array which is a state object, react way with Typescript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I need to maintain array of objects which is stored in a state object. Basically I need to push each object to this array whenever I click on Add button .This should basically store this object in array.

Also I am unable to fetch proper values when I am trying to submit?
Where am I going wrong?

Basically the structure I want is:

```
users= [
        {"name":"xxx","email":"yyy","phone":"656"},
        {"name":"yyy","email":"xxx","phone":"55"}
       ];
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
interface IState{
    users : Account[];
}
interface Account{
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string
}

export default class App extends React.Component<{},IState> {

    constructor(props:any){
       super(props);
       this.state= { 
                         users: []
                   }
    }


  handleChange = ( event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   this.setState({
    users:{
      ...this.state.users,
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    }
    })
  }

  onAdd = () => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
     users: [...prevState.users],
    }));
    console.log(this.state.users); // Unable to get the proper info
  }

  render(){
   <React.Fragment>
     <form onSubmit={this.onAdd}>
       <input type="text" onChange={(e:any) => this.handleChange(e)} name={"name"} />
       <input type="text" onChange={(e:any) => this.handleChange(e)} name={"email"} />
       <input type="text" onChange={(e:any) => this.handleChange(e)} name={"phone"} />
       <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
   </React.Fragment>
  }
}
```

Comment: In the handleChange, why do you set users to a new object containing account property, if it's an array of users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - State not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated)

Comment: you don't need handleChange, in onAdd get all inputs value from the event, put them in object( like {name: e.input.name.value ...} and set it in users(which will be an array)

Comment: @Roy.B Could you just edit the onAdd?

Comment: @velsonjr I added an answer see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to correct:-

1) You are using only one state variable `users` for one user as well as all users. So create two state variables, one for temporary storing of data for a user and `users` variable for storing all users data.

2) You are trying to access `console.log(this.state.users);` after setState but it is not in the callback, setState is asynchronous it should be in callback of setState.

3) When user submits the form, the page refreshes which is default behaviour of application, we need `e.preventDefault();` to override this behaviour.

4) Use state for individual input textboxes so that you could may be apply validation etc on fields.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface IState {
  users : Account[],
  user: Account
}

interface Account{
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      user: {name: '', email:'', phone: ''}
    }
  }

  handleChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        [event.currentTarget.name]: event.currentTarget.value
      }
    });
  };

  onAdd = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      { 
        users: [...this.state.users, this.state.user],
        user: {name:'', email: '', phone: ''}
      },
      () => {
        console.log("updated state", this.state.users);
      }
    );
  };

  public render() {
    const { name, email, phone } = this.state.user;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onAdd}>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={name} name="name" />
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={email} name="email" />
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={phone} name="phone" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Improvement Area - You could declare array of fields like fields = ['name', 'phone', 'email'] and map over in render function, this way you would need to write  form once and any no of fields could be added.**

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Could you give the typescript implementation, this seems to be giving lot of errors! Thank you

Comment: Tried this though this.setState({user: { name '',
   email: '',
   phone: ''}});
  } in the end of onAdd().

Comment: @velsonjr - Updated the code with clear fields functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Update `onAdd` like below, because `setState` method updates state asynchronously, therefore you can't get the state right after calling it, but you can do so using a callback as second argument in `setState` method which is invoked after the method has updated the state

```
onAdd = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const newUser = {}
    return {
      users: [...prevState.users, newUser],
    }
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.users)
  });
}
```

Comment: just add more keys to update in the `return` statement

Comment: I am afraid, not!

Comment: why are you so?

Comment: its simple to add the keys you want to update in the state in the return statement inside the `setState` method

Answer (score 1):

you don't need handleChange, in onAdd get all inputs value from the event, put them in object( like {name: event.target.form.elements.name.value ...} and set it in users(which will be an array)

```
 export default class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props:any){
       super(props);
       this.state = { 
             users: []
       }
    }

onAdd = (event) => {

 const user = {
   name: event.target.form.elements.name.value,
   email: event.target.form.elements.email.value,
   phone: event.target.form.elements.phone.value
  }
     this.setState({
     users: [...this.state.users, user]
    });

  }

  render(){
   <React.Fragment>
     <form onSubmit={this.onAdd}>
       <input type="text"  name="name" />
       <input type="text" name="email" />
       <input type="text" name="phone" />
       <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
   </React.Fragment>
  }
}
```

then if you log this.state.users you will get the stractue you need

```
users= [
        {"name":"xxx","email":"yyy","phone":"656"},
        {"name":"yyy","email":"xxx","phone":"55"}
       ];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export default class App extends React.Component<{},IState> {

state = {
      users: [],
      text: '',
}


  handleChange = ( event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  onAdd = () => this.setState({
    users:[
          ...this.state.users,
          {
           e.target.name: e.target.value,
           e.target.email: e.target.value,
           e.target.phone: e.target.value
          }
    ]
  })

  render(){
   <React.Fragment>
     <form onSubmit={this.onAdd}>
       <input type="text" onChange={(e:any) => this.handleChange(e)} name={"name"} />
       <input type="text" onChange={(e:any) => this.handleChange(e)} name={"email"} />
       <input type="text" onChange={(e:any) => this.handleChange(e)} name={"phone"} />
       <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
   </React.Fragment>
  }
}
```

You are setting your `users` as an array and then you are converting it into an object with the `handleChange`. Try to see if this works