# reactjs state not being updated

Tags: reactjs, setstate

in my filter() callback newList contains the correct array but state is not being updated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>list</title>
      <script src="react/react.js"></script>
      <script src="react/react-dom.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id='container'>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>


<script type = 'text/jsx'>

class FilteredList extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={list:this.props.list};
   }

   filter(input){
      var newList = this.state.list.filter(function(item){
         return (item.search(input.target.value)!=-1);
      });
      console.log(newList);
      this.setState({list:newList});
      console.log(this.state.list);
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Filter' onChange={this.filter.bind(this)} />
            <List items={this.state.list} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class List extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={items:this.props.items};
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <ul>
            {this.state.items.map(function(item){
               return(<li key={item}>{item}</li>);
            })}
         </ul>

      );
   }
}

   ReactDOM.render(
      <div><FilteredList list={['anteater','bear','cat','dog','elephant','fox']} /></div>,
      document.getElementById('container')
);
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not being updated

Comment: if i had a clue I would be researching it, hence I ask for your help. I get no errors in the console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - State not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated)

Comment: @DCR I think you misunderstood the question. They weren't asking you to guess why your code isn't working the way you expect, they were asking you to give a proper problem description by explaining what (and how) you've observed the problem, and what the expected behavior would be instead, i.e. "what makes you think something is wrong with the code, if there's no errors? tell us [in detail] what the issue is"

Comment: thanks,  I understand, although with the two console.log statements it's pretty obvious why I didn't think it was being updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `setState` is asynchronous. This means that the state is not immediately updated when the line is executed, but some moment later.

To execute code once the state has been updated, `setState` takes a callback as second argument :

```js
this.setState({list:newList}, () => console.log(this.state.list))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the state to be updated and the filtered result to display you need to re-render the child components on parent state change.

https://codepen.io/asifamingov/pen/QWwNOgQ

```
class List extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={items:this.props.items};
   }
   componentWillReceiveProps({items}) {
    this.setState({items:items});
   }
   render(){
     return(
        <ul>
            {this.state.items.map(function(item){
                return(<li key={item}>{item}</li>);
            })}
        </ul>

    );
   }
  }
```

And one more issue I found is that you are mutating your original state

```
class FilteredList extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={list:this.props.list, updatedList: this.props.list};
   }
  filter(input){
    var updatedList = [...this.state.list];
    var newList = updatedList.filter(function(item){
        return item.toLowerCase().search(
            input.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({updatedList:newList});
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Filter' onChange={this.filter.bind(this)} />
            <List items={this.state.updatedList} />
        </div>
    );
   }
 }
```