# Why is the state not available right after being set?

Tags: reactjs, state, web-audio-api

How come the following code errors with a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createOscillator' of null` when the `playTone` function is called?

I don't understand why `audioContext` is still `null` by the time `audioContext.createOscillator()` is run. I was expecting `initialiseAudioContext` to define it.

The second time `playTone` is called, the `audioContext` is defined. At first this made me think that there could be some asynchronicity happening but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
const [audioContext, setAudioContext] = useState(null);

const initialiseAudioContext = () => setAudioContext(new window.AudioContext());

const playTone = () => {
  if (!audioContext) {
    initialiseAudioContext();
  }
  const oscillatorNode = audioContext.createOscillator();
  ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - State not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated)

Comment: I haven't figured out the code yet but it points me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: @Jelefra - tldr- `setState` is `asynchronous` (think `promises`)