# FireStore: Getting Type Error when trying to add to a document to a subcollection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im creating a small react app and using Firestore as my database.
whenever the user clicks save i want to add a document to their builds subcollection.

the structure of my database is like this
[image: screenshot of firestore]

here is my code that handles the creation of their reference point in the users collection and how i create the nested builds collection. (including states)

```
const [userReference, setRef]=useState("");
const [collectionReference, setCollection]=useState("");
const [savedBuilds, setBuilds] = useState([]);

// create reference to users database paths
const handleCreatingFirestoreReference = async () => {
    if(userReference===""){
        try {
            const userPathway = await addDoc(collection(db, 'users'), {});
            setRef(userPathway);


            const userBuildCollection = collection(userPathway, 'builds');
            await addDoc(userBuildCollection,{}) //adding dummy object to ensure builds collection is created.
            setCollection(userBuildCollection);



        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating user reference:', error);
        }
    } else{
        console.log('userReference Exists.');
    }
};

const handleSaveToFirestore = async () =>{
    //get most recent loadOut from state.
    let mostRecentSave = savedBuilds[savedBuilds.length-1];
    console.log(mostRecentSave);
    
    // add most recent load out to fireStore
    try{
        let userPathwayToBuilds = collectionReference;
        let userFireStorePathway = userReference;

        await addDoc(collection(userReference,userPathwayToBuilds),mostRecentSave);
    }catch(error){
        console.log('error encounterd: ',error);
    }
}


// saves the loadOut to an array and updates savedBuilds State
const handleSaveClick = () =>{
    let savedLoadout = {
        champion:`${savedChamp[0].id}`,
        championImg:`${savedChamp[0].img}`,
        item1:`${savedItems[0].image.full}`,
        item2:`${savedItems[1].image.full}`,
        item3:`${savedItems[2].image.full}`,
        item4:`${savedItems[3].image.full}`,
        item5:`${savedItems[4].image.full}`,
        item6:`${savedItems[5].image.full}`
    }
    const isDuplicate =  savedBuildsDuringSession.some(build =>
            Object.keys(build).every(key =>
                build[key] === savedLoadout[key]
            )
        );
    if(!isDuplicate){
        savedBuildsDuringSession.push(savedLoadout);
        }
    setBuilds(savedBuildsDuringSession);
    // create reference to database
    handleCreatingFirestoreReference();
    // add most recent object from savedBuilds state to subcollection
    handleSaveToFirestore();
    }
```

However when i click save i get the following error in my catch.

```
    error encounterd:  TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function
      fromString path.ts:230
      collection reference.ts:433
      handleSaveToFirestore BuildSaver.jsx:46
      handleSaveClick BuildSaver.jsx:75
      React 23
     <anonymous> main.jsx:6
```

line 46 in my code is :

```
await addDoc(collection(userReference,userPathwayToBuilds),mostRecentSave);
```

I don't understand what i am doing wrong here. I've checked other posts on SO and went back and forth with ChatGPT and some people on Reddit about this but to no avail.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Setting state variables is an asynchronous operation. This means that the `setCollection(userBuildCollection)` hasn't completed yet by the time your `let userPathwayToBuilds = collectionReference` runs.

You should **not** use state variables for this, but regular variables and properties. In fact, I'd simplify it to:

```
async function getUserBuildCollection() {
    if(userReference===""){
        const userPathway = await addDoc(collection(db, 'users'), {});
        const userBuildCollection = collection(userPathway, 'builds');

        await addDoc(userBuildCollection,{});

        return userBuildCollection;
    } else{
        throw "getUserBuildCollection needs userReference to have a value";
    }
}
```

And then:

```
const userBuildCollection = getUserBuildCollection();
handleSaveToFirestore(userBuildCollection);
```

And then use the `userBuildCollection` from the parameter, than rather from the (not yet updated) state.

Also see:

- [React setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state)
- [React - State not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490581/react-state-not-updated)

Comment: Hi Frank - Confused on what you're simplifying - when trying to replace my current handleCreatingFirestoreReference (); with getUserBuildCollection(); I get this error:

"FirebaseError: Function collection() cannot be called with an empty path."

which points to line 39 in my code
 
await addDoc(collection(userReference,userPathwayToBuilds),mostRecentSave);

which is the 6th line in my handleSaveToFirestore() function.

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong there, which is why I started with an explanation of the problem (updating the state is an asynchronous operation) and included links to questions that explain more about this. Does the problem make sense, and did you read the links?

Comment: I have read the links thank you - But I dont understand still why the object im trying to push to the database doesn't get pushed and every click creates a new instance in users when i really just want the click to create a pathway in users then builds and have all new clicks populate in builds not create new documents for users. I hope that makes sense

Comment: The use-case makes sense. But setting state variables is an asynchronous operation. So when `let userPathwayToBuilds = collectionReference` runs, `collectionReference` hasn't been updated yet. If that isn't clear from the links, set a breakpoint each line, run the code in a debugger, and check the value of each variable on each line. That way you can see that the update hasn't happened yet, when you expect it to.